# SQL - Creating a filter for only a subgroup without using WHERE for that subgroup

Tags: sql

I have a sample database set up with the stats of all NBA players from January 1 to January 7. I have a query set up to see minutes played for all players of a team when a player is either playing or not playing using either date in or date not in. For example, here is a query for when player Courtney Lee is in:

`select player, date, tm, Minutes
from nba.player_stats 
where tm='BOS' and
date in (select date 
  from nba.player_stats 
  where player = 'Courtney Lee');`

returns:
[image]
The issue with this is that on the 5th, Courtney Lee was traded to tm MEM. He then played for tm MEM on the 7th, so it returns the data for BOS on the 7th. However, I don't want it to do this since he is no longer on tm BOS.

Ideally, I would like to not include the statement `where tm='BOS'`. I'd like to just say player in='Courtney Lee' and have it return only the stats of teams he played for on only dates he played.

This is a query I plan on running for several players from different teams at once. As it is now, I have to do it player by player, team by team, and manually filter dates when trades happen.

Comment: This is more a NBA trading problem :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure (would have liked a little data to test with), but I think you can simply do a 'self-join' between the table.

Something like:

```
select t2.*
from nba.player_stats t1
inner join nba.player_stats t2 on 
t1.date = t2.date and t1.tm = t2.tm
where t1.player = 'Courtney Lee'
```

It's a little guess-work, but .... basically it selects from player_stats where your player is Courtney Lee, then it joins into player_stats again on date and team which seems to be what you're after in your sub query in your where?

Comment: No problem - glad to be able to help @mattdh12